# Test controller in rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to write all possible tests when creating a new user

- Invalid password
- Existing user email
- Create success user

in user controller

```
 def new
    @user = User.new
  end
```

```
def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash_success('User created.!')
    end
  end
```

How can write all the above scenarios in testing?

for the last scenario "Create success user" use

```
assert_response :redirect
```

And what about others for which assert_response must be used?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your first question is not a great one. Please review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and see if you can fix it up so it can be answered.